# Make background div responsive load at browsersize

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been trying to get a responsive fullscreen at width slider to load responsive according to the browser-size, no matter if  i have content below, as in this example: http://www.wingsandhorns.com/

How would the markup for a background image, slider or any other div be to achieve this?

Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new units in css (vw and vh) for your element, let's say a div:
    #mydiv {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background: url('myimg');
    background-sizing: 100vw 100vh;
    }
This will give your element the width and height of th viewport.

Comment: Hmm couldn't get that to work? this is the site im trying it on: http://www.svenssonsbild.se/Baronen/?page_id=103 The main image is a slider, and what i want to resize itself after the browser, thus leaving the thumbs below

Comment: please provide your html :)